# ¿Como puedo quitar la Fecha de entradas especificas! en worpress?

Tags: wordpress

Los plugins que he encontrado quitan la fecha de todas las publicaciones. Quiero quitarlo de las entradas que yo elija.

Con Cogigo en function.php.

```
function jl_remove_post_dates() {
    add_filter('the_date', '__return_false');
    add_filter('the_time', '__return_false');
    add_filter('the_modified_date', '__return_false');
    add_filter('get_the_date', '__return_false');
    add_filter('get_the_time', '__return_false');
    add_filter('get_the_modified_date', '__return_false');
} add_action('loop_start', 'jl_remove_post_dates');
```

No me sirve, quiero quitarlo de solo algunas entradas que yo elija, o incluso categorias. Como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que intentaste? porque basicamente estas pidiendo que alguien lo desarrolle por vos, y para eso no es esta pagina...